# The syntax for running Junit from commandline in Mac

Tags: java, macos, junit, command-line, terminal

I want to run Junit from commandline in Mac OS but Im not able to get it to work as expected with a simple test class that I have created.

I have downloaded `junit-4.12.jar` for this purpose and been writing a very simple test class with one simple test method.

Im running with the following command to compile the class:

```
javac -cp .:/Full/path/to/junit/junit-4.12.jar DemoTest.java
```

..and running the following command to execute the compiled class:

```
java -cp .:/Full/path/to/junit/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore DemoTest 

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DemoTest {

    @Test
    public void evaluate(){
         assertEquals(true, 1<2);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see "test pass" when I am running the junit class from commandline, because that's what it should generate. Instead Im getting the following error message (please note that Im only pasting the first line of error for the sake of simplicity):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Does this mean that Im only missing the `hamcrest.jar` file to be able to run the application as expected?

Please let me know if you need the complete error stacktrace!

Comment: Just for the record: nobody who does serious unit testing runs JUnit manually (like that). Meaning: ideally, you use a build system like gradle or maven ... and you have a project definition for that. And then you simply tell the build system, to say: run all unit tests. You see: running a simple test class is easy. But normally, you have your production code (under test), and your unit tests. And you want to ensure that everything was compiled nicely, and so on. Rest assured: if you want to do serious work, then you are asking the wrong question ;-)

Comment: You're setting the classpath to the current directory and the junit jar--you are ignoring any/all dependencies.

Comment: @GhostCat Im aware of that. I just simply wanted to run a simple test in commandline just to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

mentioned you miss the `hamcrest-core` library in your class path. Download it and add it to the classpath

```
java -cp .:/Full/path/to/junit/junit-4.12.jar:/Full/path/to/hamcrest/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar  org.junit.runner.JUnitCore DemoTest
```

Comment: And whatever other dependencies junit and hamcrest-core has.

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was missing to include in compilation and execution process. I downloaded it from the Maven repo and add it in the same folder and that fixed it.